# Call to undefined function method_field()

Tags: laravel, lumen

I have created a view for lumen with this code:

```
<form action="{{ route('extentions.update', ['id'=>$extention->id]) }}" class="form" method="POST">
        @method('PUT')
        @include('extentions._partials.form')
        <button type="submit">Enviar</button>
    </form>
```

However i am getting the error `Call to undefined function method_field()` when opening this view, does Lumen not have the @method function? If so, what should I do?

Comment: lumen doesn't even come with a view system as its for stateless apis ... so probably not ... `method_field` just adds a hidden input named `_method`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">` instead of `@method('PUT')` worked.